# Post data to MVC controller from DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a MVC, multiple select `DropDownList` that populates the Select Items from a `SelectListItem` model.

`@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeStatuses", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EmployeeStatuses, new { multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 100%;", @class = "select2", onchange = "UpdateEmployeeStatusFilter()", id = "employee-status-type" })`

When the user selects or unselects items from the `DropDownList`, I want to run a method in my controller that will filter the data in the view. This is done with the `onChange` event `UpdateEmployeeStatusFilter()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateEmployeeStatusFilter() {
      var value = $('#employee-status-type').val();
      console.log(value);
      var a = ["X", "Y", "Z"];
      console.log(a);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SearchEmployee", "Employee")',
        data: { valueMember: value },
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (msg) { alert(msg) }
    });

    };
  </script>
```

When I debug the script, I am able to get the value of `value` and write that to the console window. When the controller method is called, the value is `null`.

```
public IActionResult SearchEmployee(string itemsSelected)
{
    // Do Stuff with itemsSelected
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**My question is how do I get that value into my controller?**

I am not sure if this code is relevant or not, but I will include it for clarity.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Get Employment Statuses
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statuses = _mockDataRepository.GetEmployeeStatuses().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.ValueMember,
        Text = c.DisplayMember,
        Selected = c.ValueMember == "AC"
    });
    ViewBag.EmployeeStatuses = statuses;
}
```

```
public class SelectListItem
{
    [Key]
    public string ValueMember { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name mismatch. The `SearchEmployee()` action method has `itemsSelected` input parameter. Therefore set the same parameter name in the `.ajax` call:

```
data: { itemsSelected: value },
```

Comment: Ugg, that was the issue. The least you could have done is made it look a little more difficult! Just as a note for others, since the values are in an Array, I had to change the line  var value = $('#employee-status-type').val(); to var value = new Array($('#employee-status-type').val());